# Search by images in firebase android

Tags: image-processing, firebase, face-detection, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

in the new skd of firebase it is supprot to upload images to the storage, and that is very awesome.
after uploading images to firebase how to search in these images and get similar images ? 
or that will need another thing to implement ?

Comment: There are great tools for recognizing objects in images. But they are not part of Firebase Storage and recommending one (*cough*Google Cloud Vision API*cough*) is off topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: is that will let me send him an image and then let them search to my images in storage ?